# CSS Selector: find dd element corresponding to a dt tag?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to get the anchor of a `dd` element corresponding to a `dt` tag.

My code looks like

```
<dl>
<dt> Web URL </dt>
<dd> <a href = "link"> name </a></dd>  <--- want to get the name corresponding to the Web URL dt tag.
</dl>
```

Currently I am using the CSS selector as :

```
dl dd:nth-child(8) a
```

Is there a better way, I can do this using the dt element ?

Comment: *"want to get the name corresponding to the Web URL dt tag."* You can't target an element by it's content using only CSS. You are limited to tag, class, id, attribute, or pseudo-class. If you need to target the `<a>` with the text content of "name" by targeting a `<dt>` with the text content of "Web Url" you'll need JavaScript.

Comment: Solved it using xpath: `.//dt[contains(text(),'Web URL')]/following-sibling::dd[1]`

Comment: See my answer for a simpler solution.

Comment: I see now that my addition of the [css] tag was in error. Judging by the asker's use of XPath it seems that they aren't really looking for a CSS solution after all. Which makes me puzzled as to why they accepted your answer, @zer00ne.

Comment: @BoltClock I believe OP wanted the `<a>`nchor of the `<dd>` and thought there was a way using CSS to hook into the `<dt>` text content somehow. The comment in the first snippet indicate's intent is to get the "name" and there's anchor with content of "name". Second clue was in the second snippet of a selector: `dl dd:nth-child(8)` **a** . TBH I was kind of surprised the answer was accepted because I was 50% sure that my deductions were correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have deduced your intentions, you want to get a specific `<a>` by its text content. With CSS you can target by its `href' attribute and its value. With JavaScript and jQuery you can target it's text content. The following demo shows a way using JavaScript, jQuery, and CSS.

**Details commented in demo**

### Demo

```js
/* JavaScript change color to gold
==================================
|| Gather all <a> in a NodeList
*/
var lnx = document.querySelectorAll('a');

/* Loop thru lnx with for...of loop
|| On each iteration, check to see if
|| any <a> have the content: ' alpha '
|| and then change the color to gold
*/
for (let a of lnx) {
  if (a.textContent === ' alpha ') {
    a.style.color = 'gold';
  }
}

/* jQuery change the font-size to 40px
=======================================
|| Find all <a> that contains the text: ' alpha '
|| Change its font-size to 40px
*/
$('a:contains( alpha )').css('font-size', '40px');
```

```css
/* CSS change background to black
=================================
|| Find all <a> with the href property that
|| has the text 'Alpha' anywhere in its value.
|| *= {Anywhere in value}
|| ^= {Beginning of value}
|| $= {End of value}
*/


/* ^= would work in this case as well */

a[href*='Alpha'] {
  background: black
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt> Web URL </dt>
  <dd> <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha"> alpha </a></dd>
  <!-- want to get the name corresponding to the Web URL dt tag.-->
  <dd> <a href="https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bravo"> bravo </a></dd>
  <dd> <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie"> Charlie </a></dd>
  <dd> <a href="https://www.delta.com/"> delta </a></dd>
  <dt> Site Map </dt>
  <dd> <a href="echo.html"> echo </a></dd>
  <dd> <a href="foxtrot.html"> foxtrot </a></dd>
  <dd> <a href="golf.html"> golf </a></dd>

</dl>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're asking OP to embed the entire jQuery library into their application? That is incredibly overkill, and it doesn't seem to answer the question. Here you have 4 `dd` elements which correspond to the 'Web URL' `dt` element and 3 which correspond to the 'Site Map' element, yet you're only selecting one `dd` element. I really don't feel that this answer gives all that much to the question which was asked.

Comment: Read carefully, the demo has 3 examples: one in JS, one in jQ, and one in CSS. The only example that needs jQuery is the jQuery example. Read the question very carefully and despite what the question asks, the OP's true objective is to get a specific `<a>`nchor. My CSS example is the most efficient and fulfills OP's objective as well as meeting the limitations set by the tags. Look at OP's  second Snippet: `dl dd:nth-child(8) a` therein reveals the true question and OP's intent. Besides, if my answer was the one accepted it goes to show that this answer was the best solution for the poster.

Comment: Also here within the OP's first snippet is a comment: `<--- want to get the name corresponding to the Web URL dt tag.` The"name" is the text of an anchor. The poster was fixated on the `<dt>` probably because he/she did not know or didn't recall that an element could be referenced by its attribute and its value.

Answer (score 4):

The [adjacent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) or the [general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) sibling operator may help. Example

```
dt + dd { ... }
```

will match every `dd` element which follows a `dt` element directly, or

```
dt ~ dd { ... }
```

will match `dd` elements having a `dt` element as any predecessor.

You can combine these operators with more complex selector, too:

```css
dt + dd a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<dl>
<dt>Test</dt>
<dd>Name</dd>
<dd><a>URL 1</a></dd>
<dt>Web URL</dt>
<dd><a>URL 2</a></dd>
<dl>
```

The CSS rule will only match for `URL 2`.

Comment: Two problems here: **1.** A `dt` can have multiple `dd` elements following it, and your `dt + dd` example will only select the first. **2.** Your `dt ~ dd` selector will select all following `dd` elements, regardless of whether there's another `dt` between them.

Comment: If the dl consists only of single dt-dd pairs, #1 may be a non-issue. #2 is much more critical.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: You can specify the selectors more precisely, e.g.: `dt.web-url ~ dd.name`. I've added an example.